# Is it possible to configure Azure Machine Learning deployed inference container to use a Kubernetes persistent volume?

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks, azure-machine-learning-service, persistent-volumes

I have a real time inference container (Real-time inference endpoint deployed with a custom Docker Environment) and I would need it to have access to a persistent volume claim.

The inference container is deployed to an AKS cluster using the AML SDK v1:

```
from azureml.core.model import Model
Model.deploy()
```

I have tried to configure the Kubernetes cluster to have a PV and a PVC according to the instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/reference-kubernetes#azureml-jobs-connect-with-custom-data-storage).

The labels and annotations for the PVC are in place but the volume is not visible in the container. I have also checked that the pods are in the same namespace with the PVC.

I just noticed that the instruction seems to be under the SDK v2 section and now I'm wondering if it only works with that. Does anyone know if I just have to change to the v2 or should it work like this with v1 also? Or is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: I just got confirmation from Microsoft that at least for now the persistent volumes are not available for inference endpoints.